# Can we use geoNetwork with php

Tags: php, geonetwork

I am new to GIS, I want to develop web application using geoNetwork, Is it posible to use PHP with geoNetwork?

Comment: What kind of application do you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean with "use with php"? Geonetwork is written in Java.

Comment: Thank you til_b and johanvdw Yes i have a geoNetwork server with H2 database, Now i want to build a site using PHP and search data with geoNetwork, So is theere any PHP api to connect with geoserver and get search result.

Comment: Is it possible create a PHP web with geoNetwork? i want to create web portal to show stored information on geoNetwork.

Comment: Would you be able to use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with any clarifications that come out as Comments, please?  That way it continues to standalone without having to read a trail of Comments.

Comment: @PolyGeo Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Theres a "kind of" API (read: some features are available through HTTP requests) described at http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/developer/xml_services/index.html .

From that document:

```
Url:
http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/xml.search

Mime-type:
application/xml

Post request:s
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <any>africa</any>
</request>
```